# React Router v4 in production with Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

Im attempting to deploy my code to apache. Im using `react router 4` and `connected react router` with `create react app`.

The app is deployed to a nested directory, like this: `http://example.com/pathTo/myApp`

There are 2 optional parameters. When the first is used, it works fine. When there is an additional paramter, there is an error.

- http://example.com/pathTo/myApp/about -> works fine
- http://example.com/pathTo/myApp/property/23423 -> Error: Unexpected token <

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <      1.9adc2a7a.chunk.js:1

**package.json**

```
...
"homepage": ".",
...
```

**store.js**

```
export const history = createHistory({
    basename: "/pathTo/myApp",
})
```

**index.js**

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`/:viewType?/:viewID?`} component={App} />
                <Redirect from="*" to="/about" />
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    target
);
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /pathTo/myApp/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I was just about to ask a similar question.

Comment: No unfortunately i did not. The furthest I got was setting the `base href` in the index.html to the base url, allowing the URL parameters to work on initial load but still not rewriting the URL correctly.

Comment: Hmmm - there has to be a way to do this, otherwise anyone with a blog or anything like that that has dynamic content would not be able to share it

Comment: I agree, i would like to resolve this issue.  I simply ran out of time and since it wasn't a requirement of the project I decided to deploy as-is for now.

Comment: Wrapping my app in `import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';` so `<HashRouter><app /></HashRouter>` I finally got this to work - ugly URLs but a price worth paying for me - can refresh dynamic pages on Apache server and routing works if any good to you mate

Comment: Ah ok. Not sure I will be able to go that route as I am already using hashed params w/mapbox-gl in my app. Latitude,longitude and zoom level are parameterized this way. For example, `http://example.com/pathTo/myApp/property/219?layers=buildings#34.44/23.233/7`

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595175/how-to-deploy-and-host-react-app-on-apache-server/64210568#64210568). Maybe it helps.