# How to deploy and host react app on Apache server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, production

I have created a dashboard by using "React js" for Frontend and "Node js" for Backend. Now the project is completed, I need to deploy and host this project on Apache server.
I have tried by running the "npm run build" then copying all the files of build folder to the server but still its not running.

```
Error: The requested URL /Dashboard was not found on this server
```

So can anyone help me out with this ? Because I am new to these whole web development stuff.
If anyone tell me what are the configurations needed to make this happen, it will be helpful a lot.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "eclaims",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "alert-node": "^1.2.4",
    "await": "^0.2.6",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "browser-history": "^1.0.1",
    "canvasjs": "^1.8.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express-redirect": "^1.2.2",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "http-serve": "^1.0.1",
    "mdbreact": "^4.14.0",
    "oracledb": "^3.1.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-background-image-loader": "0.0.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-canvas-js": "^1.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.6.4",
    "react-dropdown-button": "^1.0.11",
    "react-native": "^0.59.8",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redirect": "^1.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-select": "^2.4.3",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "redirect": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I also tried by creating the ".htaccess" file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

But still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed certain steps from this [post from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4e6lbt/getting_react_routing_to_work_with_apache2) and I can attest this works for making SPAs run in Apache web server with proper routing.

To quote:

> 1) In the `apache2.conf` located in `etc/apache2/` I turned `AllowOverride` to `All`. I also added Servername localhost in the file. (I somehow skipped this last sentence, but still it worked fine in the end)
>
> ```
> <Directory /var/www/>
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ```
>
> 2) In the `hosts.debian.tmpl` file found in `/etc/cloud/templates` I added `127.0.0.1 <yourdomain.com>` to the file where the other ips of the similiarity are.
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
> ```
>
> 3) I ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. Then I restarted the apache server via `service apache2 restart`. This turns on mod_rewrite.
>
> Lastly inside of my project folder `/var/www/html` , along side my `index.html` file I created a `.htaccess` file and added in the following:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
> RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
> ```

Assuming you've run `npm run build` and then copied all the contents inside the `build` folder to your public directory, this should work.

When I first started web dev, I wasn't really sure I made the VirtualHost config right, so what I usually did was first to make a dummy index.html with, say, Hello World example. When I've confirmed that I'm able to see Hello World in the browser (which means I got the VirtualHost config right), I dump the contents of the `build` folder to where the dummy index.html was.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

**Apache:**

I am running an Apache Server with multiple React-Apps, that are accessible by Aliases, as e.g. `/abc/app/` or `xyz/app/`. For that paths, i adjusted the `<Directory>...</Directory>` area inside my virtual hosts config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
RewriteEngine On

    Alias /abc/app "/var/www/abc"
    Alias /xyz/app "/var/www/xyz"

    <Directory "/var/www/abc">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
     </Directory>


    <Directory "/var/www/xyz">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
     </Directory>

    [...]

</VirtualHost *:443>
```

Additionally, I added the following into `/var/www/abc/.htaccess` according to the [React Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

**React Router > 4:**

But most importantly I adjusted my `package.json` and `.env` files. If you use environment files, you can add the following lines (obv adjusted with your path) to your production or release environment files:

```
PUBLIC_URL=https://link.to.your.page/abc/app/
REACT_APP_ROOT_PATH=/abc/app
```

**Don't rename PUBLIC_URL. You can change everything after REACT_APP_**

Delete the `homepage` line from your package.json

Alternatively, if you don't work with `.env` files, you might adjust your `homepage` line in the package.json like so:

```
 "homepage":"link.to.your.page/abc/app/"
```

In your `index.js`, or where ever you use BrowserRouter or Router, you alter your code like so:

```
 let PATH = process.env.REACT_APP_ROOT_PATH // Or, if you prefer it hard coded "/abc/app"
 <BrowserRouter basename={PATH} > <App/> </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

React is for front-end. I guess you want to say, apache and nodeJs